# Component name as string

Tags: vue.js

I have a registered custom filter component like:

```
import Filter from "../components/DataTableComponent/StringFilter";

components: {
  Filter
},
```

I can use this component in a vue2-datatable column like:

```
var col : { title:"Foo", field:"Bar", comp: Filter }
```

Basically, I want to give this component a name as a string from my service and render it is like one like above.

```
var col : { title:"Foo", field:"Bar", comp: "Filter" }
```

Comment: Didn't get your question very accurately ? Do you want to map your component name- Like if your service sent you name of a  component `A` and you want to render `B` for it ?

Comment: @SatyamPathak You are very close. Actually, my service give me exact name of component and I want to render it. Normally in SPA, we should give this component name as import (import Filter) name as you know. But service give me string.

Comment: Ok so you want to dynamic import a component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Requirement is that you are trying to send `component` object to the wherever you want to send. So it's simply a basic concept to store it to the instance you working currently and use it dynamically.

Service sends you component name - `"Filter"` and you are importing the same name component  to your file.

Just store it to a object then after like this

```
import Filter from "../components/DataTableComponent/StringFilter";

// store it to local object
const componentReference = { Filter }

// Let say service sent you this name
const componentNameSentByService = "Filter"

//reference it to using the name dynamically using object
var col : { title:"Foo", field:"Bar", comp: componentReference[componentNameSentByService] }
```

Comment: It's tricky and works. Thank you but I thought there is more elegant way to do this.

Comment: Your welcome - But No , i don't think so as - I didn't find anywhere in the `Vue` docs stated that it exposed the component references to a variable. You can't find the name to the instance of the component `this`. The only way is to catch the reference of the component - `refs` which in your case doesn't apply. However I also didn't find the solution any how tricky it's just how you communicated through object.